# Массив битов сконвертировать в char или int

Tags: массивы, c

Приветствую! Задачка вот какая... есть массив `unsigned char data[2]`, который забивается битами (нулями и единицами). В исходном коде для вывода на `UART` была реализована такая конструкция.

```
  printf_P(s_code);
  for(a=0; a<=bit; a++){
        if(data[a/8]&(1<<(a%8))) uart_putchar('1',stdout);
        else uart_putchar('0',stdout);
                }
  uart_putchar('\n',stdout);
```

мне надо на выходе получить обычный `char`. Пробовал по-всякому, но что то не допру

Comment: Что значит "обычный char"? bit, как я понял равен 15. Вы выводите единички-нули, начиная с младшего разряда на stdout. Какой char из двух (data[2]) Вам нужен?

Comment: оба бита. по сути надо привести их в 16-ричное текстовое представление. bit = 11.

Comment: Попытайтесь представить, что я должен понять из написанного Вами. Давайте так: что на входе (в hex), что на выходе в hex (и где этот самый выход).

Comment: ох, не умею я объяснять) есть исходный бинарный data[11] (объявлен как data[2], но в ходе программы в него попадают 11 бит), надо эти биты для читабельности представить в виде А1С, например.

Comment: Попробуйте

    short *p = (short *)data;
    for (i = 0; i < bit/2; i++)
       printf("%x ", p[i]);

Comment: @baralgin1003

      ох, не умею я объяснять)

Это означает, что программирование не для Вас? Круто. (Компутер -- максимальный идиот. Не можете объяснить человеку -- ему не сможете никогда).

data[2] или data[11]? Что есть A1C? Это 0xA1C? (Не лезет в 11 бит -- требуется двенадцать) Давайте пример с конкретными значениям в hex. И распишите по байтам. (Может в процессе и сами поймёте, что Вам надо)

@avp У него bit = 11 или больше. А data[2]. Ваша программа сойдёт с ума.

Comment: @alexlz, Вы правы. Я по невнимательности решил, что у ТС массив двухбайтовых значений и он хочет увидеть их в 16-ричном виде.

А у него всего 2 байта (ну, 11 интересных ему бит), а вот что он от них хочет не пойму...
Если просто напечатать 11 бит в hex, то можно так:

     printf("%x%x\n", data[0] & 0xff, data[1] & 0x7);

это как его программа печатает 0 и 1.

Comment: да, точно так и надо. Спасибо!

Comment: @baralgin1003, я угадал? Очень рад.

Comment: @avp экстрасенс!